Constrained optimization with restriction
I am studying optimization of function in two variables $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$
I have seen two techniques that involve restricitons of the function $f(x,y)$ used for constrained optimization when the constraint is of type $g(x,y)=0$ with $ g \in C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$:

One says that we can write the constraint $g(x,y)=0$ as a curve in parametric form $r: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and then study the derivative of the restriction by using $\frac{df(r(t))}{dt}=\nabla f(r(t)) \cdot r’(t)$ and finding its zeros
The other one says that we can write the constraint $g(x,y)=0$ as a curve in parametric form $r: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and then study the one variable function $\frac{df(r(t))}{dt}$ but really treating it as a one variable function and not using the formula above. I’ve only seen this one in exercises. An example is, if we are given $f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ (so $g(x,y)=0$ is the unitary circumference which is $r(t)=\cos t, \sin t$ as a curve with $t \in [0, 2\pi ]$), then we substitute $x$ with $r_x(t)=\cos t$ and $y$ with $r_y(t)=\sin t$ and we obtain $f(r_x(t), r_y(t))=1$ and we take its derivative which is 0, without using the formula with the gradient as for 1). This is similar to another restriction technique, where we isolate $x$ as a function of $y$ from $g(x,y)=0$ and substitute it in $f(x,y)$ which becomes $f(y,y)$ and then we study it as a function in one variable.

My question is: do 1) and 2) yield the same results? It seems to me that 2) is faster since it requires less calculations, but only 1) uses the proper formula for the derivative of the composition of a multivariable function with a curve.

In your example, do you mean that $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$? You wrote $f$, but if that's $f$, then what is $g$?

@5xum thanks, I wrote i$g$ only in parametric form already, as $r$. Now added

Both methods will yield the same result, it's just a matter of when you perform the algebraic manipulation.

In your first case, you first calculate the derivative of $f$ and $r$ and then combine them, and only then simplify the expression to get the derivative of the composite function.
In the second, you calculate the composite function first and then calculate the derivative.

Both methods are perfectly valid, and it's a case by case basis to determine which is simpler.
